# How to get a list of unique cart products

Tags: magento2

for example i use code for my custome shipping method

```
    $totalItems = $cart->getQuote()->$getItemsQty();
```

Total count of products (example add 2 bags adidas and 1 top nike = **total 3 items**)

But how to get unique items? (example add 2 bags adidas and 1 top nike = **total 2 items**)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code helped me

```
   $cart->getQuote()->getItemsCount()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the cart items' info with the below code.

```
$allItems = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();
$totalCount = sizeof($allItems);
foreach ($allItems as $item) {
            echo $item->getItemId();
            echo $item->getName();
            echo $item->getSku();
        }
```